# How to prevent XSS in an embed element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, embed, xss

I have the following React component which is vulnerable to XSS via the content inside the PDF when it is rendered.

The component looks like this:

```js
import i18n from "i18next";
import React, { memo } from "react";

import k from "../i18n/keys";

class PDFPreview extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filePreview: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = `data:application/pdf;base64,${this.props.file}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.blob())
      .then(x => this.setState({ filePreview: URL.createObjectURL(x) }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div key={this.props.key}>
        {this.props.file && this.props.file != "null" ? (
          <embed
            name={this.props.key}
            style={this.props.pdfStyle}
            type="application/pdf"
            src={this.state.filePreview}
            height={setHeight(this.props.height)}
            width={setWidth(this.props.width)}
          />
        ) : (
          <div>{i18n.t(k.CANNOTLOADFILE)}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default memo(PDFPreview);
```

The file contents are passed as a base64 string and then rendered inside the embed component as HTML.

I have this simple XSS payload which looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj
<</Pages 1 0 R /OpenAction 2 0 R>>
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Action
/S /JavaScript
/JS (app.alert('XSS');)
>> trailer <</Root 1 0 R>>
```

I need to sanitize the contents of the HTML rendered inside the embed. I've tried sanitizing the HTML multiple ways (DOMPurity and custom functions as well), tried iframe with sandbox and also sanitizing the content of the PDF itself, but to no avail. The XSS is always reflected and alert is shown.

Is there any good way sanitize the contents of the embed element in javascript?

Comment: Use Server Side Sanitization: At server, parse PDF content and check for any JS actions. Check this out for  [further information](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)